# Micro-Controller Programmable Selection

Tags: microcontroller, programming, c++

I have searched a lot and I can't seem to find a micro-controller that I can program in C++. Can someone please help me find a micro-controller (besides Arduino) that I can program C++?

Comment: Any microcontroller can be programmed in C++. You just have to find a C++ compiler for them.

Comment: @m.Alin Not if it doesn't have any RAM, correct?

Comment: @BenjiWiebe Your question doesn't make sense to me. What does the RAM have to do with C++? And what microcontrollers don't have RAM?

Comment: Did you perhaps mean not *enough* RAM?

Comment: @JoeBaker There are controllers without RAM, are there not? All they have is CPU registers. And C/C++ require a stack, located in RAM.

Comment: Oh, I thought you meant as in C vs C++ memory requirements, OK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can program AVR microcontrollers in C++, though most people program AVR's in C or assembly. You will have to buy a programmer, [AVRISP mkII ($37 @ DigiKey)](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en/programmers-development-systems/in-circuit-programmers-emulators-and-debuggers/2621880?k=AVRISP%20mkII), and then a microcontroller (for example, [ATmega16A ($4.75 @ DigiKey)](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/ATMEGA16A-PU/ATMEGA16A-PU-ND/1914560)).

Then you will need to download [WinAVR](http://sourceforge.net/projects/winavr/)([download](http://sourceforge.net/projects/winavr/files/WinAVR/20100110/WinAVR-20100110-install.exe/download)) and [AVR Studio](http://www.atmel.com/tools/ATMELSTUDIO.aspx) (Windows)

OR Install the `avr-gcc-c++` package(Linux).

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thank you so much!!! This is exactly what I was looking for! Though can I use any Atmel Micro-Controller with the programmer? Thanks!

Comment: Most. AFAIK, the entire AVR tiny and mega series are compatible with this programmer. Not sure about the XMEGA, AVR CAN, AVR USB, etc. If you like this answer, upvote it and/or click the checkmark by it to accept it.

Comment: Thanks! That's all the info I need. Sorry, don't have enough reputation to upvote.

Comment: @user1832583 You have it now. ;)

Answer (score 2):

A microcontroller can be programmed in anything, as long as there is a Compiler for that language and microcontroller. You need to look for a compiler for the mcu you want to use.

That said, aside from the others listed, the MSP430 and the Stellaris ARM microcontrollers from Texas Instruments are programmable in C++ with the (mostly) free IDEs (Integrated Development Environment) Code Composer Studio (Based on Eclipse), or IAR. You can also use MSPGCC in linux systems.

The Microchip Pic line also has C++ compilers available, including a free one with their MPLAB IDE, for both 8bit and 32bit pics.

Comment: Why was this voted down?

Answer (score 2):

My favourite is the LPC1114:

- available in DIP package,
- 32K flash, 4K RAM,
- $3 from mouser in Q 1,
- serial bootloader on the chip,
- internal 12 Mhz oscillator OK for serial communication,
- GCC avaiable from Mentor/Codesourcery (but note that the 64-bit operators are wrong!!).

I made a small make-based development package (with corrected 64-bit operators) for it that I will use in my lessons. C next quarter, probably C++ after the holidays and assembler after that.

Answer (score 1):

ARM Cortex M4, M3, M0 architecture MCUs are good options.
ARM9 architecture MCUs are also.
PIC32 series MCUs.
i.MX series MCUs.

http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/MK10DN512ZVLK10R/MK10DN512ZVLK10RCT-ND/3488933

http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/PIC32MX795F512H-80I%2FPT/PIC32MX795F512H-80I%2FPT-ND/2184448

http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/STR912FAW47X6/497-9039-ND/2035403

http://www.nxp.com/products/microcontrollers/cortex_m4/

http://www.st.com/web/en/catalog/mmc/FM141/SC1169/SS1577

http://www.freescale.com/webapp/sps/site/training_information.jsp?code=WBNR_KINETIS_ARMCORTEX&tid=mKhp

http://www.freescale.com/webapp/sps/site/homepage.jsp?code=IMX_HOME

Comment: Thank you very much! Could you please provide me links to their distributers? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[Atmel AVR](http://www.atmel.com/products/microcontrollers/avr/default.aspx) processors can be programmed in C++ using avr-gcc which is part of the [WinAVR package](http://sourceforge.net/projects/winavr/). This set up can be used on Arduino if that is your choice of board.

Comment: I think I beat you to this answer... There aren't any hard feelings though... ;)

Comment: Could you give me a link to the chip? Thanks!